# Trying to understand a java function parameters

Tags: java, function, parameters

My teacher assigned a question and here it is:

Write a program that inputs words into an array. The program will stop when a word is entered twice. Use the following method:

```
static boolean findWord(String s, String[] arr) 
// return true if s is found in arr, false otherwise
```

When the input is complete, your program will output the list in sorted order.

I am kinda lost on this parameter of the function

```
String[] arr
```

What type of parameter input is it searching for. Here is my code so far.

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
        c = new Console ();

        String words[] = new String[50000];

        for(int i=0;i>-1;i++) {
            c.print("Input word: ");
            words[i]=c.readLine();

            findWord("apples",What goes here?);
        }
    }

    static boolean findWord(String s,String[] words) {
        return false;
    }
```

Any time I try to put in some sort of array or values in the spot, such as

```
findWord("Hello",words[0])
```

or whatever I get the following error:

```
No applicable overload method named "findWord" was found in type E3_Q5. Perhaps you     wanted the overloaded version "boolean findWord(java.lang.String s,java.lang.String[] words);" instead?
```

What does this mean? What does he want me to put there?

Comment: What does `words[0]` do? What does your method expect as a second argument?

Comment: I don't know. Ask my teacher. Also words[0] Accesses the 0 index of the words array.

Comment: What is `findWord` supposed to do? What does it need to do its job?

Comment: I am assuming, it needs the current word and the array location then returns true or false if it found that word in the array

Comment: If you don't understand your assignment, _you_ need to ask your teacher for clarifications. Your method is declared as `static boolean findWord(String s,String[] words) {`. The second parameter is of type `String[]`. What are you passing as a second argument in `findWord("Hello",words[0])`? What is `word[0]`?  
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`String[] arr` refers to an array of type `String`.

Using `findWord("Hello",words[0])` does not work because you are only providing one String `words[0]` when the method or function expects `words` or the **whole array** called `words`.

Try this instead"

```
findWord("apples", words);
```

Note:  You will need to modify your method `findWord(String s,String[] words)` as it currently will always return `false`.

```
public static boolean findWord(String s, String[] words) {
    for(String word : words) {
            if (s.equals(word))
                return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't a for loop take in three pieces? When I tried (String word : words). I received a misplaced constructs error.

Comment: @unableToCompile It's called [Enhanced for loop](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/using_enhanced_for_loops_with), it's perfectly fine.

Comment: This code checks the entire array of duplicates each call. You should see something is wrong because the parameter `s` isn't used. You need to loop over the array and search for `s`. In any case, posting all the code doesn't help the OP learn.

Comment: I just copied and pasted an old method without checking, my apologies.  I fixed it.

Comment: So, My code compiles but always returns true, why is that? http://pastebin.com/KKmsqgLc

Comment: http://pastebin.com/UVnxi4Gy, I edited it a bit as well.  Reasons for changing certain elements are in the comments.  Hope this helps.

Comment: OP start with tutorials here, they are 100x better then any textbook/proff generated notes.  Start at the top and work your way down.   http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reallybigindex.html

Answer (score 0):

`words[0]` is no longer a String [] (a string array). It's just a string. Java lets methods have the same name and accept different parameters--which is called overloading. The method needs a string array though, so lop off the [0] and you'll be on your way to further implementing the method.

findwords("apple", {"apple", "banana", "cookie"});

Comment: can you show an example of     findWord("apples",X);   I think you mean this findWord("apples",words);

Comment: You are correct in that. I added an example to the bottom. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Your function

```
findWord(String s, String[] arr)
```

need a String as first argument and an array of Strings for second argument.

According to your Porblem it should be:

```
findWord(words[i],words);
```

where words[i] is the current word and words are all words. if this function returns true, so the current word is found in words and your program should terminate.